# opencart 2.0 корзина

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, opencart

Добрый ночи дорогие друзья, делаю свой магазин на opencart информации товаров беру из api, можно ли взаимодействовать с корзиной, например как сбросит товары в корзину если работать не локально, можно ли использовать функции движка такие как добавлении товара в корзину, и как все это можно сделать или придется все же сделать свою корзину при работе с api.

Comment: https://freecart.pro/forum/blogs/entry/39-api-sistema-opencart/

Comment: Беру с api т.е используя другой сервис (taobao) т.е сделано отдельное страница где выводится информации от товаре с таобао, дальше если конфигурации выбрано надо сбросит товар в корзину opencart 2.0 т.е товары нету на базе а лишь артикл и конфигурации. Который и надо прикрутить к корзине opencart 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Штатными методами, думаю, не получится. **opencart 2** оперирует только своими товарами, т.к во время добавления в корзину используются записи о товаре из бд и переменные сессии. Если вы дропшипер, то вам надо сперва полученные списки товаров  загнать в целевой магазин на опенкарт а потом уже дёргать за евонное **API**.

Или ищите расширения реализующие подобный функционал.

Comment: Тогда, другой вопрос нельзя ли прикрепит свою корзину к аккаунту? и в какую сторану направится? я вижу на opencart в stackoverflow только вы активно отвечаете, наверное у вас большой опыт на opencart

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Опишите функционал, который хотите реализовать, подробнее.

Comment: Хочу пересобрать оформление самому, если дропшипер нельзя прикрутит в системную функции корзины, у меня ведь все работает по api, тогда придется сделать модуль корзины надо же как то взаимодействовать корзину с пользователям.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать такие вещи. У opencart 2 есть встроенный апи, который дает возможность манипулировать товарами, 
я делал так
если нужно купить товар которого нет на сайте, а который прилетает из вне, 
я добавлял в апи конструктор, на проверку данного товара, если такого нет, то создавал данный товар в базе с уникальными индификаторами ( какой сайт, какой айди в другой системе, ну остальное по стандартному ), короче тянул его с другого api
, ну а после делал afterCreate и уже добавлял в корзину.

Еще встречал другой подход, который динамически создавал нужный товар для покупки, а после транзакции удалял его, тоже имеет место быть, но тогда при каждом запросе заново приходится проделовать все действия

Comment: Я щас делаю по другому. Делаю отдельный модуль корзины и туда перехватываю регистрацию. Правда от opencart остаются только mvc и личный кобинет

Comment: по сути вы полностью избавитесь от всех удобств . которые предоставляет цмс...